# Add PostgreSQL dependency with spring-boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, maven

I'm trying to setup my postgreSQL connection with my db and I have this NoClassDefFound error when I add postgresql dependency in my pom while doing a mvn clean install. I think it might be a casual error but I'm new to Spring and I can't find a proper explanation on forum. I also tried to specify postgresql dependency version but didn't get much results out of it.

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

Here is my application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    platform: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mtc_db
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    database: postgresql
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

And my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>mtc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mtc-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mtc-api</name>
    <description>API for MTC application</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.8.21</kotlin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                        <!-- Or "spring" for the Spring support -->
                        <plugin>all-open</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <pluginOptions>
                        <!-- Each annotation is placed on its own line -->
                        <option>all-open:annotation=com.my.Annotation</option>
                        <option>all-open:annotation=com.their.AnotherAnnotation</option>
                    </pluginOptions>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Use the `PostgresqlDialect` instead. Newer versions of hibernate don't include the one you mentioned any more. Also remove the `spring.jpa.database` property as that does the same as the dialect (they should be mutually exclusive imho).

Comment: Thanks you for your answer and your time. I will try that as soon as I get back home and will keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect must be set to org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect